# Proper formatting for this MYSQL query required

Tags: mysql

Struggling to get the correct MYSQL query assembled to do the following:

2 Tables (Locations and Venues).
In Locations I want to get the Unique location_name and location_id Where there is a venue with on_website = 1
This is to draw a drop down list for navigation.

So I have London as a location and in London I have several venues
In Wilmslow I have a location but there are not venues that I want to advertise (on_website = 0 on those)

Currently I get the output

```
Bath
London
Birmingham
London
Bristol
London
```

Where I would want

```
Bath
London
Birmingham
```

Tried this:

```
SELECT 
  tblLocations.location_name,
  tblLocations.location_id,
  tblVenues.venue_id
FROM
  tblLocations
  INNER JOIN tblVenues ON (tblLocations.location_id = tblVenues.location_id)
  Where tblVenues.on_website = 1
```

And tried using distinct but It still gives me duplicate locations.

Any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  tblLocations.location_name,
  tblLocations.location_id
FROM
  tblLocations
  INNER JOIN tblVenues ON (tblLocations.location_id = tblVenues.location_id)
  Where tblVenues.on_website = 1
```

You have to use distinct without the venue_id, because the venue_id is different for different rows in your query. Distinct only filters exactly matching rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd listed all three selected columns, you'd saw that each of them are unique. That's how `DISTINCT` works. Just do not select fields you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY could do the trick

```
SELECT 
  tblLocations.location_name,
  tblLocations.location_id,
  tblVenues.venue_id
FROM
  tblLocations
  INNER JOIN tblVenues ON (tblLocations.location_id = tblVenues.location_id)
  Where tblVenues.on_website = 1
  GROUP BY tblLocations.location_id
```